# Casting from const char arr[] to char **

Tags: c++, casting, constants, function-declaration

So i have the following situation:

```cpp
void func(char ** a)
{
// Do some stuff...
}

int main() 
{
    const char * arr[2] = { "foo" };
    arr[1] = "bar";

    // I want to Cast the arr from const char ** to char **
    func(arr);
}
```

I think `func(reinterpret_cast<char**>(arr));` is a way, but i don't know if it's the best way.

Thank you!

Comment: `const_cast` is how you add or remove const-ness, but that also removes const-correctness. The correct way to solve this issue is to write `void func(const char** a)`

Comment: The even more correct way to handle this is to use `std::string`. If this isn't a homework assignment that has forbidden you from using `std::string` You should use `std::string`.

Comment: I can't change the func signature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters this declaration

```
const char * arr[2] = "foo";
```

is incorrect. Arrays are aggregates and initializers of their elements shall be enclosed in braces.

```
const char * arr[2] = { "foo" };
```

Used in expressions the array (with rare exceptions) is converted to pointer of the type `const char **`.

This function

```
void func(char ** a)
{
// Do some stuff...
}
```

does not accepts a pointer to pointer to constant data. It means that the function can change pointed data. This in turn means that you shall not pass your array to this function.

What you could do is to allocate dynamically an array of arrays like for example

```
char **p = new char *[2];

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
{
    p[i] = new char[4];
}

strcpy( p[0], "foo" );
strcpy( p[1], "bar" );

func( p );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
{
    delete[] p[i];
}

delete[] p;
```